# iOS NSLog %hd %hhd %ld and %lld format specifiers

Tags: ios, string-formatting, nslog

What would be the meaning of these format specifiers?

```
%hd %hhd %ld %lld
```

Comment: The "String Format Specifiers" documentation explicitly links to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html.

Answer (score 9):

%hd is used for `short integer` or `unsigned short integer`

%hhd is for `short short integer` or `unsigned short short integer`

%ld is for `long integer` or `unsigned long integer`

%lld is for `long long integer` or `unsigned long long integer`

Simple as that.

Here `h` , `hh` , `l` , `ll` are just length modifiers in %d

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such thing as a `short short int`.

Comment: I know, there is no such thing as a short short int, that's just a char which is the smallest integer storage class in C. But I didn't have that much time to explain it to him + I want him to go through the documentation if he wants to learn, not just expect answers from SO.

Answer (score 3):

Just look into the Documentation from Apple provided here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

I think [this document](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/standlib/ref/printconversionspecifiers.htm) from IBM is a bit better.So:

```
  %hd       int x          (short)x           10     1
  %ld       long x         (long)x            10     1
```

Comment: Seems that your link has expired. Found the new place but I am not sure whether it is the document you had in mind... - http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.cbcsl01/printconversionspecifiers.htm