# How can I know how much space to allocate for an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I am creating a simple program (code below), which asks user for his/her name, and says hello back to you. I was just wondering if the comments I made in the code are correct. I am trying to understand how arrays are created, and how we allocate space for them, and deal with them, so we don't go out of bounds in memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// "-" (no quotes, just the dash) means garbage values
int main() {

    char name[5];
    // name = [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
    //         -   -   -   -   -   -

    char fav_nums[5];
    // fav_nums = [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
    //             -   -   -   -   -   -

    printf("What is your name (max characters 5)?\n");
    scanf("%s\n", name);
    // I typed "Sammy" (no quotes)
    // name = [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
    //         S   a   m   m   y   \0

    printf("Hi, %s\n", name);

    printf("Enter your 5 favorite numbers!\n");
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
        scanf("%d", fav_nums[i]);
        i++;
    }
    // I typed 2 3 6 7 1
    // fav_nums = [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
    //             2   3   6   7   1   -

    fav_nums[5] = '\0';
    // fav_nums = [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
    //             2   3   6   7   1   \0


    printf("Cool, I love");
    i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
        printf(" %d", fav_num[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I was just wondering the comments I made in the code are correct." no, they are not. An array has valid indexes from `0` to `size - 1` so the first index of `char foo[5];` is `0` and the last is `4`.

Comment: Also, you should not use `scanf("%s" // ...` without limiting the number of `char`s to read: `scanf("%4s\n", name);` --> 4 `char`s and the terminating `'\0'` at max. ... Siddig El Tahir El Fadil El Siddig Abderrahman Mohammed Ahmed Abdel Karim El Mahdi would have problems using your program, though.

Comment: @Swordfish but I thought when you do `char foo[5]` it means indexes 0 - 4 are for characters and index 5 is for the '\0'? Or is this only true for int arrays?

Comment: `int i = 0; while (i < 5) {/* ... */ i++;  }` just BEGS to be a `for`-loop: `for(int i = 0; i < 5 ++i) /* ... */`

Comment: A well enabled compiler would warn about bad code like `char fav_nums[5]; ... scanf("%d", fav_nums[i]);`.  Save time and enable all warnings.

Comment: @Swordfish I love the structure of a while loop better than a for loop

Comment: @Sukku: again: `some_type foo[N];` is `N` times `sizeof(some_type)` big. Its valid indexes are `0` ... `N-1`. There is no mechanism to make some `foo[x]` to be `'\0'` automagically.

Comment: @Sukku: when `for` is appropriate it is easier to read.

Comment: @Swordfish so what is stored in N?

Comment: @Sukku it was just a general example. In `char name[5];` the `N` would be 5. Valid indexes: `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`. `name` is `5` `char`s in size. `"sammy"` is too big for a `char[5]`.

Comment: @Swordfish For example. If I enter "Samm" in `char name[5]` these are the indexes? `[0] = S` | `[1] = a` | `[2] = m` | `[3] =m` | `[4] = ??? (whats here)` | `[5] = ??? (whats here)`

Comment: "`[4] = ??? (whats here)`" the `'y'`. "`[5] = ??? (whats here)`" thats the problem. `name[5]` is not part of the array `char name[5];`, writing to that is undefined behaviour (= not allowed). Thats why I said "you should not use `scanf("%s" //` ... without limiting the number of chars to read" earlier.

Comment: @Swordfish no I entered "Samm" not "Sammy". Could you explain with "Samm" example. For now, we can assume the user will always type the correct amount of letters

Comment: if you have a `char name[5];` and `scanf("%s", name);` and the user enters `Samm`, `name[0] == 'S'`, `name[1] == 'a'`, `name[2] == 'm'`, `name[3] == 'm'`, `name[4] == '\0'`.

Comment: @Swordfish if we name `name[5]`. And `name[0]` starts at `memory 1000` and `name[1]` is at `memory 1001`. That means the `name` array starts at `memory 1000` and ends at `memory 1004` (inclusive). `memory 1005` might be used by another variable like `city[0]`

Comment: @Suku si, senor!

Comment: @Swordfish and this logic applies to any type of array? Like an int array or a double array?

Comment: @Suku si, senor!

Comment: Thank you @Swordfish I understand now. One final question. When I type `char name[5]`. The 5 means, allocate me 5 bytes of space? 4 bytes for my characters and 1 byte for my null terminator?

Comment: 4 bytes for characters max because a "C-string" needs a terminating `'\0'`, yes.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I know how much space to allocate in an array?

Let us take a look at the name first.

Good, you are asking for input with an upper bound.

```
printf("What is your name (max characters 5)?\n");
```

---

Bad, `name[5]` is too small to hold as a *string*, a name with 5 characters. `"%s"` is bad.  No limit on input.  Do *not* scan for whitespace after the `"%s"`.  It blocks until following non-white-space detected.  Check return values.

```
// bad
char name[5];
scanf("%s\n", name);
```

Instead `name[]` needs room for 5 charters and a  *null character*.

```
char name[5+1]; 
if (scanf("%5s", name) == 1) Success();
```

---

Use a matching specifier and type.  A good well enabled compiler would have told you this already and saved us all time.

```
// not 
char fav_nums[5];
scanf("%d", fav_nums[i]); // bad char,%d
// Instead 
int fav_nums[5];
scanf("%d", fav_nums[i]); // good int,%d
// or 
signed char fav_nums[5];
scanf("%hhd", fav_nums[i]); // good signed char,%hhd
// or 
unsigned char fav_nums[5];
scanf("%hhu", fav_nums[i]); // good unsigned char,%hhu
// or 
char fav_nums[5];
int num;
scanf("%d", &num); // good int,%d
fav_nums[i] = num;
```

---

**Deeper**

If you want code to do it robustly, code need to check more tings.

Separate out input from data storage.

Use `fgets()` to read user input, allowing a buffer of at least about 2x the expected max needs.

This is then large enough to handle the data, a `'\n'`, a `'\0'` and extra leading, in-between, final white-space, and perhaps uninformative leading `'0'`s on numeric input.

With 2x, code also does not allow mis-use and abuse of exceeding long input.  Such input should be detected and flagged as hostile.

After reading data into the buffer, parse it for a *name* and save to `name[]`.

Some pseudo code

```
char buffer[2*sizeof name];
fgets(buffer, ...);
trim_leading_trailing_whitespace(buffer);
insure_not_too_big(buffer, sizeof name);
copy buffer to name
```

Comment: Whats `%hhd` mean

Comment: @Suku: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854628/ios-nslog-hd-hhd-ld-and-lld-format-specifiers

Comment: @Suku `"%hhd"` with `scanf()` is for writing a `signed char`.  `"%d"`  is for writing an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @chux' answer, if you want to read a line of arbitrary length:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *name = NULL;
    size_t length = 0;
    size_t size = 0;
    size_t const buffer_growth = 10;  // +10 ... or whatever length you expect

    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' && ch != '\r')
    {
        if (length + 1 >= size) {
            if(size + buffer_growth <= size)  // we reached or overflow the max
                break;                        // object size on the platform

            char *new_name = realloc(name, size += buffer_growth);
            if (!new_name) {
                free(name);
                fputs("Memory allocation failed :(\n\n", stderr);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            name = new_name;
        }

        name[length++] = ch;
        name[length] = '\0';
    }

    printf("\"%s\"\n", name);
}
```

Comment: UV for quality "read a line of arbitrary length" code.  Yet I forgo the arbitrary length on user input these days as it provides a hacker exploit: allowing an external user to overwhelm memory resources with a _long_ line.  Instead I promote allowing for a generous, yet limited input buffer size and fail exceeding long input.  Of course for a learner like OP, good to learn various approaches to solve a coding task.

Comment: @chux how could an input method like shown in the answer be exploited?

Comment: Exploit: User enters data gigabytes long text in order to use significant memory resources.  Possible to cause some failure with subsequent  string code to mis-handle a 2G string or even a simple direct out-of-memory here.  Even [long names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Blaine_Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff_Sr.) are less than 1000 `char`.

Comment: @chux No way to exploit out of mem in my example. If `size_t` overflows strange things will happen, agreed.

Comment: @chux added code to prevent `realloc()`ating < `size` bytes ^^